# how to integrate paypal with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway

I'm trying to integrate PayPal payment with my codeigniter project. My project is about a dating site, in which two different users interact with each other. So I'm selling plans, on the based of which users will be provided access to send messages to to other for the that period of time. For that i have developed a very simple page containing radio buttons to choose from different plans.
These are the following plans

> - one month (`$2`)
> - Two month (`$4`)
> - Three month (`$6`)
> - Four month (`$8`)
> - Five month (`$10`)

and so on

> - Six month (`$12`)

So, user can choose anyone plan from the above and can then proceed further to pay the amount on PayPal. This page will be available to user who have accounts on our site.
so we can transfer all the details of current user to PayPal, such as -- name,email,etc..

I have tried reading many articles on how to integrate paypal but none of them helped me.
As I'm new to codeigniter.

I have also created Paypal and sandbox account on paypal. I downloaded php-toolkit from sourceforge.net and used it independently, then it runs properly. but when i try to implement in codeigniter, it does not take anywhere.

Please help me !!

**EDIT :**

```
<?php 

    //Configuration File
    include_once APPPATH.'../php_paypal/includes/config.inc.php'; 

    //Global Configuration File
    include_once APPPATH.'../php_paypal/includes/global_config.inc.php';

?> 
<?php echo form_open('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');?>   

 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9.95">
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Payment">
</form>
```

This is what i'm simply trying to create. Earlier i tried to use "process.php" in the form action, but i was getting URL error in codeigniter. So i thought why not use this way. I know there are function responsible which are sending values to paypal. But through this action method. I'm being redirected to simple paypal page.

Comment: Then you should post the code you're using for Codeigniter, so that we could see where you're doing wrong

Comment: @DamienPirsy --- i have updated my question, could you please check it again and reply back ? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the steps you can follow.

**Step1** Create IPN Form. make sure to pass IPN URL (notify URL) to paypal.

For Form variables, you can refer https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

```
<form name="paypalFrm" id="paypalFrm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_ext-enter">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $return_url;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo $cancel_return;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo $notify_url;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $custom.",".$custom2;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $business_id;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $item_name;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="<?php echo $plan_amount;?>">  
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">  
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">   
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="srt" value="12">
    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $txtname;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="<?php echo $merchant_country;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $txtemail;?>">
</form>
```

**Step 2** Create IPN controller. For detailed understanding review https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value); }         

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

$header = ''; 
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen('www.sandbox.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables

$content['payment_status']      = $this->input->post('payment_status');
$content['payment_amount']      = $this->input->post('mc_gross');
$content['payment_currency']    = $this->input->post('mc_currency');
$content['txn_id']              = $this->input->post('txn_id');
$content['receiver_email']      = $this->input->post('receiver_email');
$content['payer_email']         = $this->input->post('payer_email');    
$custom                         = explode(",",$this->input->post('custom'));
$content['payment_id']          = $custom[0];
$content['type']                = $custom[1];
$content['txn_type']            = $this->input->post('txn_type');        
$content['paydate']             = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


if (!$fp)
{
    // HTTP ERROR
}
else
{

    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    if (!feof($fp))
    {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);

        if(strcasecmp($content['txn_type'], "subscr_payment") == 0)
        {
            //Action            
        }
        else if(strcasecmp($content['payment_status'], "Completed") == 0)
        {
            //Action            
        }
        else if(strcasecmp($content['txn_type'], "subscr_cancel") == 0)
        {
           //Action            
        }
    }
    fclose ($fp);
}
```

Comment: pardon me. if i go wrong somewhere. Firstly i'm trying to take user for payment from my site to paypal. how should i achieve that?

Comment: If you can observe HTML form; this form is getting submitted to Paypal for payment. That means you just need to call submit action of this form and it will take user to paypal for payment.

Comment: Thank you so much for ur fast response. Finally i got the result. But there was a problem, it redirects to a paypal page where paypal makes mandatory to register on there site. But earlier when i tested it with php-toolkit, it redirects to a different page, where paypal gives both option of registering and direct payment also.

I also need one more help, i don't know what all details are required from admin side when actual payment is made. and where we can take details dynamically, such as merchant-id, signature etc ?

Comment: Well Pankaj, Merchant Id is required to make payment to the business account and for rest of the details please read HTML form Variable document of paypal. That will help you out. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Comment: Hello Trimantra -- although i have successfully inserted data into database using ipn controller given by you. But i'm trying to print the $_POST variable, and I'm not getting anything. So how can i print all values posted by paypal, or how can i know what all values are send by paypal in IPN.

Comment: Pankaj IPN works in background and called by paypal. So in front end you cannot print IPN POST data. you can store IPN in database just for a record or you can simply email IPN string to admin email id and check details. In my code above **"$req"** is IPN string.

Comment: Hello @TrimantraSoftwareSolution, Is this form secure, i mean if some one change values in this form, then from will send that values instead our suggested?
If some one change bussiness email then transaction will be maid to that email.

Answer (score 0):

```
$orderide = $this->checkout_model->user_order($order_table);
$business='paypal@business.example.com';            
$cancel_url="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/checkout/cancel?orderide=".$orderide;
$success_url="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/checkout/success?order_id=".$orderide;
$data['payment_url']="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=$business&cmd=_xclick&item_name=$title&item_number=$product_id&amount=$totalamount&currency_code=EUR&return=$success_url&cancel_return=$cancel_url";              

redirect($data['payment_url']);
```

**In `return success URL` you can able to get the user id and payment amount**

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Download the CodeIgniter PayPal library from here: https://github.com/nrshoukhin/codeigniter-paypal-library.

Step 2: Drag and drop the entire "application" folder from the library to your codeigniter project. Make sure it's not conflict with your existing files.

Step 3: Load the library from your controller construtor:-

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library("paypal");
}
```

Step 4: Open the file from "application/config/paypal.php". And provide your client ID, client secret and currency.

Step 5: Create a controller method like below:-

```
public function subscribe(){

    if ( !empty($_POST["plan_name"]) && !empty($_POST["plan_description"]) ) {

        $this->paypal->set_api_context();

        $this->paypal->set_plan( $_POST["plan_name"], $_POST["plan_description"], "INFINITE" );

        $definition = "Regular Payments";
        $type       = "REGULAR";
        $frequency  = "MONTH";
        $frequncy_interval = '1';
        $cycles = 0;
        $price = "49";

        $this->paypal->set_billing_plan_definition( $definition, $type, $frequency, $frequncy_interval, $cycles, $price );

        $returnurl = base_url()."payment/success";
        $cancelurl = base_url()."payment/cancel";

        $this->paypal->set_merchant_preferences( $returnurl, $cancelurl );

        $line1 = "Street - 1, Sector - 1";
        $city  = "Dhaka";
        $state = "Dhaka";
        $postalcode = "12345";
        $country = "AU";

        $this->paypal->set_shipping_address( $line1, $city, $state, $postalcode, $country );

        $agreement_name = "Payment Agreement Name";
        $agreement_description = "Payment Agreement Description";

        $this->paypal->create_and_activate_billing_plan( $agreement_name, $agreement_description );

    }

}
```

Here, set the frequency as "MONTH" and set the frequency_interval according to your desired recurring period.